# Can't decrypt using crypto module in Nodejs

Tags: php, node.js, codeigniter, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to write a script which equivalent to php opensssl decryption, this is what i have tried,

```
var crypto = require('crypto');
var ct = 'jKscKK6E/aQ50hAck0YZkA==';
var key = 'gxmo872UXsU6u41t2zXzRNcU9H1cfuNvu/fnI/q1vIc=';
var iv = 'sd+XF3bRJ/WMT9woe8LOkQ==';
var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', new Buffer(key, 'base64'), new Buffer(iv, 'base64'));
var content = decipher.update(new Buffer(ct, 'base64'), "binary", "utf8");
content += decipher.final("utf8");
console.log("Decrypted: " + content);
```

but i got this error,

> Error: Invalid key length

This is the php code i am trying to equivalent

```
openssl_decrypt(base64_decode($ct), 'aes-128-cbc', base64_decode($key), OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, base64_decode($iv))
```

Comment: You aren't base64 decoding your key/IV anywhere.

Comment: **What** PHP OpenSSL decryption would that be? Supply the source!

Comment: @MaartenBodewes https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/libraries/Encryption.php and refer line 626

Comment: @LukeJoshuaPark, i missed the decoding parameter in buffer, after added that now error says Invalid Key length.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My intention was to write a script which is equivalent to Codeiginiter default decryption, so i begin with the bottom of the code, that's where i found above error, in the end i was able to write whole script, hope this may be helpful for someone.

```
  let crypto = require("crypto");
  let secret = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';

  // ikm is initial keying material
  var hkdf = function (hashAlg, salt, ikm) {
      this.hashAlg = hashAlg;

      // create the hash alg to see if it exists and get its length
      var hash = crypto.createHash(this.hashAlg);
      this.hashLength = hash.digest().length;
      this.salt = salt || new Buffer(this.hashLength).fill(0).toString();
      this.ikm = ikm;

      // now we compute the PRK
      var hmac = crypto.createHmac(this.hashAlg, this.salt);
      hmac.update(this.ikm);
      this.prk = hmac.digest();
 };

 hkdf.prototype = {
    derive: function(info, size, cb) {
      var prev = new Buffer(0);
      var output;
      var buffers = [];
      var num_blocks = Math.ceil(size / this.hashLength);
      info = new Buffer(info);

      for (var i=0; i<num_blocks; i++) {
        var hmac = crypto.createHmac(this.hashAlg, this.prk);
        hmac.update(prev);
        hmac.update(info);
        hmac.update(new Buffer([i + 1]));
        prev = hmac.digest();
        buffers.push(prev);
      }

      output = Buffer.concat(buffers, size);
      return output;
    }
 };

 function decrypt(code)
 {
    if (typeof code !== 'string')
       return false;
    code = code.substring(128);
    var buff = new Buffer(code, 'base64');
    var iv = buff.slice(0, 16);
    var encyptedText = buff.slice(16).toString('base64');
    var _hkdf = new hkdf('sha512', null, secret);
    var derive_key = _hkdf.derive('encryption', secret.length);
    var key = derive_key.slice(0, 16);
    var decipher = crypto.createDecipheriv('aes-128-cbc', key, iv);
    var result = decipher.update(encyptedText, 'base64');
    result += decipher.final();
    return result.replace(/[']/g, '');
 }
```